# Is there an effect analogous to the slowing down of massive particles in Newtonian cosmology?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, newtonian-gravity

We know that massive particles slow down by $a^{-1}$ in the *Robertson-Walker metric* , where $a$ is the scaling factor.

If the particle velocity is non-relativistic, can we understand this slowing down effect in terms of the Newtonian model, where the universe is understood to be an expanding fluid?